# PHP/GD How to save a template generated image to recall/redraw later without saving the actual image?

Tags: php, mysql, image, save, gd

I'm creating png images from a series of layers. Example being lineart, shading, and base color (base color changes via script) with PHP's GD library by imagecopymerge.

That's perfect, but now I need to save (thousands of pngs from being generated from the templates) to individually display as they were originally generated.

Because **EVERY image on the website is created from a template**, is there any way I can redraw/re-display at will a specific generated image again without actually saving the image itself? Like just the color data and some sort of pointer to the template files?

I know it's a newbie question but I just can't seem to find the answer- I'd immensely appreciate any nudge in the right direction or link to a documentation/video to read over. Or a paid course even if it covers this specific issue. Thank you so much for reading.